# What is this syntax? [[Prototype]]

Tags: javascript

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Specific example: "o.[[Prototype]] has properties b and c"

I tried typing "o.[[Prototype]]" into the console then it gave me an error.

Comment: read the yellow box at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Inheritance_with_the_prototype_chain - which is in the page you linked to in your question!!!!!!!!

Comment: The syntax only applies to documentation. The double brackets mean that "Prototype" is an internal property, only accessible directly by the engine itself. You can use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` to retrieve its value.